# Need help for tabularx table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I need some help regarding formatting a table in tabularx (I'm only allowed to use tabularx). I'm encountering some problems and I can't diagnose the issue as this is the first time I am using Latex.

This is the code which I written so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

\multirow{2}{*}{xxxxxx} & \multirow{2}{*}{xxxxxx} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}    {xxxxx xxxx} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{xxxxxxxxxx}     \\ \cline{3-9}

 &  & xxxxxxxx  & xxxxxxxxxxx   & xxxxxxxx & xxxxx  & xxxxxxxxx & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{xxxxx} \\ \hline

xxxxxxx et al. (1900) & xxxxx & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{xxxxxx} & xxxxxxxxx & xxxxxx & xxx & $\thicksim$x km & for x = 0.1 \\ \cline{8-9}

& & & & & & & $\thicksim$y km & for x = 0.2 \\ \cline{8-9}

& & & & & & & $\thicksim$z km & for x = 0.3 \\ \cline{8-9}

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I got the result as shown below  (the first 2 rows are headers):

[image]

The problems I faced for this table were:

1) How do I remove the blank spaces along the columns which are not affected by the cline function?

2) The first column contains a citation. How can I make the author's name wrap within the cell? This is circled in blue

3) For the cells circled in red, how can I shift them up, so that they are just below the ***~x km for x = 0.1*** row?

4) How can I get rid of the | vertical separators between the third and fourth columns after the top 2 header rows??

Thank you all in advance.

Regards
Corse

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, It really helps if you post examples that people can tun to see the problem and test answers, `\begin{document}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}` would generate an error. (I fixed it this time:-)

Comment: You have specified all the columns except the first as `c` which does not allow linebreaking, then put so many `x` in each cell that the table is wider than text width and tabularx can do nothing about that. So you need to restructure your table, or use a smaller font, or allow line breaking, but without real text it is a bit hard to suggest the best places to allow line breaks.

Comment: If you run the complete document as shown in the edited question you do not get any breaks in the vertical lines. If you do, then please edit the question to add whatever non-standard definitions you have that are causing that, otherwise it is not possible to tell you how to avoid those gaps.

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply. In fact I counted the number `x` such that they correspond to the original length of characters. In that case, should I convert all the `c` to `x`?

Comment: @David what does it mean by a non-standard definition?

Comment: Perhaps, it is your table, it is very hard to guess how it should be laid out:-) If it is a table of numeric data 999 times out of 1000 it would be better set with a normal tabular than tabularx as line breaking makes no sense in such a table.

Comment: Copy the example document from the question and run it through latex, you do _not_ get breaks in the vertical lines. If you are getting breaks then you have a package that has redefined the tables in some way.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm currently using : **Copernicus Publications Manuscript Preparation Template** I tried what you mentioned and realised there really wasn't any vertical breaks. Strange!

Comment: @David, also my data is mostly characters, with the exception of the numbers shown in the questions

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your data fit in the space, tabularx isn't really going to help with that, so I used a normal tabular (you could use tabularx and just not use its features but that just slows things down)

as `xxxxxx` is never going to automatically hyphenate I added hyphenation points by hand (`\-`) (and changed a few `x` to other random letters so I could see which entry was which). This still has a couple of slightly over-full entries, but more or less fits. in the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\small
\caption{This is a table}
\begin{tabular}{|
*{10}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.9cm}|}
} \hline

xx\-xxxx &
xxx\-xxx &
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering}p{2cm}|}{xxxxx xxxx} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{xxxxxxxxxx}     \\ \cline{3-9}

 &  & xxa\-xxx\-xx  & xxxq\-xxxx\-xxx   & xxxw\-xxxx & xxxxx  & xxxk\-xxxxx & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{xxxxx} \\ \hline

xxx\-xxxx et al. (1900) & xxxxx &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{xxxxxx} & xxy\-xxx\-xxx & xxxxxx & xxx & $\thicksim$x km & for x = 0.1 \\ \cline{8-9}

& & & & & & & $\thicksim$y km & for x = 0.2 \\ \cline{8-9}

& & & & & & & $\thicksim$z km & for x = 0.3 \\ \cline{8-9}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```